# Cleanup of .sparkStaging directory on HDFS isn't performed occasionally

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

We're performing spark-submit with --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster.

We're noticing some weird behavior with regards to the .sparkStaging directory.

Most applications are deleted after they completed their run.
However, some applications remain there, with an empty directory, or some incomplete set of jars (usually they require more).

These applications IDs are not showing up in the YARN resource manager logs or UI, nor do they appear in the Spark history server or in any logs I could think of looking at.
They appear only in this directory, and are not being deleted like other applications.

The last log entry for such an application is usually:

```
INFO  Client:54 - Preparing resources for our AM container
```

In a normal application run, after this log entry, the resources are uploaded to HDFS to the .sparkStaging directory and then the application is submitted and etc.

I suspect there might be an issue with the upload process in those cases, but even if so, why is the directory not deleted after a while?